# JDBC - How to set char in a prepared statement

Tags: java, jdbc, prepared-statement

I cannot find any method like

> char c = 'c';
>
> preparedStatement.setChar(1, c);

How to set character to a prepared statement?

Comment: why not use `setString`?

Comment: Or maybe try `preparedStatement.setObject(1, c, java.sql.Types.CHAR)` ?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

The [JDBC Specification 4.0](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr221/index.html) in Appendix B (Data Type Conversion Tables) states the following conversions:

This table also shows the conversions used by the SQLInput reader methods, except that they use only the recommended conversions.

```
JDBC Type              Java Type
-------------------------------------------
CHAR                   String
VARCHAR                String
LONGVARCHAR            String
NUMERIC                java.math.BigDecimal
DECIMAL                java.math.BigDecimal
BIT                    boolean
BOOLEAN                boolean
TINYINT                byte
SMALLINT               short
```

*TABLE B- 1  JDBC Types Mapped to Java Types*

Therefore `PreparedStatement.setString(1, String.valueOf(myChar))` should do the trick.

Comment: you mean PreparedStatement.setString(1, String.valueOf(myChar)) right?

Answer (score 5):

Use setString() to set the variable.

To get it back use getString() and assuming it is not null do something like this to get the character:

```
getString("your_column").charAt(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
PreparedStatement.setString(1,c+" ");

PreparedStatement.setString(1,String.valueOf(c));
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding _how_ and/or _why_ it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.