# MySQL query INSERT in Java

Tags: mysql, jdbc, netbeans

I am using Netbeans and in this method I have som String and int variables that I would like to insert in the MySQL database.

I have tried this, but still it wont work.

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO cars (Manufacturer, Color, Extra, Country, Price)" "VALUES (variableManufacturer, variableColor, variableExtra, variableCountry, variablePrice)";
```

**Table name**  Cars

**Colummns**  `Manufacturer, Color, Extra, Country, Price`

> All the colummns are VARCHAR, except Price, it is an int.

Netbeans crashes, and it says that it cannot find variables. Anyone?

Comment: [*Use of Prepared Statements*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) solves your problem

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO cars(Manufacturer, Color, Extra, Country, Price) VALUES(variableManufacturer, variableColor, variableExtra, variableCountry, variablePrice)";
```

**Update**

i think this link can help you

[Inserting records into a MySQL table using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18270414/inserting-records-into-a-mysql-table-using-java)

Comment: I don't think it will work either, because the variables need to be taken cared of in some other way, maybe with + * ' or something.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO cars (Manufacturer, Color, Extra, Country, Price)";

sql + = "  VALUES (variableManufacturer, variableColor, variableExtra, variableCountry, variablePrice)";
```

Comment: I don't think it will work either, because the variables need to be taken cared of in some other way, maybe with + * ' or something.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :)

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO cars (Manufacturer, Color, Extra, Country, Price) "
+ "VALUES ('"+variableManufacturer+"', '"+variableColor+"',
           '"+variableExtra+"', '" +variableCountry +"', 
           "+variablePrice+")";
```

Comment: This answer is considered bad practice as it is open to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: @user5165120 I would strongly recommend referring to my answer and not use this approach. You will be open to SQL injection attacks in the future and it is bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is a [PreparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) in Java.

Something like;

```
PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO cars (Manufacturer, Color, Extra, Country, Price) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)");
```

You would then use the `ps.SetXX()` method with your variables, in your case being `VARCHAR` which I believe falls into the `String` conversion type: [JDBC - How to set char in a prepared statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5686514/jdbc-how-to-set-char-in-a-prepared-statement)